# open specific html slide from iOS code

Tags: javascript, html, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

i have html file with 5 slides i need to go to page when enter its number in text Field (or if press button) where can i go from here (how to get reference & open it ) and this is my code

```
localContent = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60, 1024, 768)];
   NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"inDirectory:@"Edge"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [localContent loadRequest:request];

    [self.view addSubview: localContent];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used java script bridge example found in https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge

and then

```
  NSString *returnvalue = [hema stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"                    $('#txt').val(19)"];
NSString *returnvalue2 = [hema stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"  $('#Stage_Nav_Bar_go_to_slide').click()"
                          ];

[WebViewJavascriptBridge enableLogging];

_bridge = [WebViewJavascriptBridge bridgeForWebView:hema webViewDelegate:self handler:^(id data, WVJBResponseCallback responseCallback) {

}];
```

it work fine for me